# mongodb javascript dirver with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use a variable in aggregation for the $match operator. Something like:

```
rating_collection.aggregate(
            {$match:{course_id:my_course}}, //<---- this is the variable, not working
            {$group: 
                { _id:null, course_total:
                    {$avg:'$course_rating'}, 
                    instructor_total:
                    {$avg:'$instructor_rating'}
                }
            }, function(error, result) {
                if( error ) { 
                                console.log(error, this);
                                callback(error);
                            }
                else { 
                    console.log("results : " + require('util').inspect(result, {depth:null}));
                    callback(null, result);
                }
        });
```

If I hard code a string instead of `my_course` I get expected results. However, not if I set the variable and then call the aggregate with that variable. Can someone explain ? Is there a solution ?

EDIT:

since the `course_id` I was looking for is an ObjectId in another document. I tried the following, which strangely works ....

```
{$match:{"course_id":new ObjectID(my_course).toString()}},
```

If anyone can shed any light on this, I guess it might be a driver issue ?

Comment: Actually `new ObjectID(my_course)` should work equally as well. The `ObjectID` type is really what is expected there in order to serialize the request properly. Other values could produce unexpected results. Works as designed.